# CRAN's glmnet version 1.9-8 doesn't support predict.cv.glmnet though documentation says otherwise

Tags: r, glmnet

I have version 1.9-8 of R's *glmnet* package installed on my Mac (OS X version 10.9.4) and I am using RStudio version 0.98.1091. When trying to run the `predict.cv.glmnet` function, I get the following error after importing *glmnet* with `library(glmnet)`:

```
Error: could not find function "predict.cv.glmnet"
```

However, I'm certain that this function is supported by the *glmnet* package because 1) it exists in the help file and 2) it exists in the reference manual for the package.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: how about `glmnet:::predict.cv.glmnet(...)` ? S3 methods need not be exported to be useable by the package

Answer (score 4):

It's a hidden function not meant to be called directly. You should just use the generic `predict()` function on a `cv.glmmet` object. From the examples on the `?predict.cv.glmnet` help page

```
library(glmnet)

x <- matrix(rnorm(100*20),100,20)
y <- rnorm(100)
cv.fit <- cv.glmnet(x,y)
predict(cv.fit,newx=x[1:5,])
#               1
# [1,] -0.1052239
# [2,] -0.1052239
# [3,] -0.1052239
# [4,] -0.1052239
# [5,] -0.1052239
```

Notice we just call `predict()` and because `class(cv.fit)=="cv.glmnet"` it calls this special version of the function.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for this! I hadn't heard of hidden functions before,